# jQuery differentiate between page load and refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to differentiate between page load and page refresh in jQuery. I have no idea how to implement the following code.

```
if( /* this page is loaded reffered */ )
    ++count ;
else if( /* this paged is refreshed */ )
    alert("refreshed");
```

Comment: Is it because you need to persist some kind of state between refreshes? If so, you could use some kind of server-side `session` control. Otherwise, you could use a cookie client-side.

Comment: It is essentially the same thing. But in asp.net you can try your luck with `IsPostback` property if refresh/reload is initiated by some control (like button). Otherwise you need to maintain some counter/flag in session to know if page is loaded first time in this session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a simple counter won't work. I'll try to illustrate it in semi-pseudo-code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(isPageLoadCookiePresent){
     //this is a page load
     setPageLoadCookie();
  }else{
     //this is a page refresh
  } 
});
```

Alternatively, instead of setting a cookie, you could use the HTML5 web storage API.

```
saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  window.localStorage.setItem('value', area.value);
  window.localStorage.setItem('timestamp', (new Date()).getTime());
}, false);
textarea.value = window.localStorage.getItem('value');
```

Taken from [here](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#web-storage)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the hash to implement this:

```
var loc = window.location,
    isLoad = false;
if (String(loc.hash).indexOf('loaded') === -1) {
    loc.hash += 'loaded';
    isLoad = true;
}
```

Then just check isLoad to see if it's a refresh or not.